# Websockets using laravel websockets, redis for backend and default websocket api for client

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, redis, laravel-websockets

I was researching how to implement WebSocket functionality using Laravel, and I came across various solutions that involved additional packages like Pusher, Socket.IO, Echo, and Echo Web Server.

I'm curious to know if it's feasible to implement WebSocket functionality solely using Laravel WebSockets, Redis, and the WebSocket API native to modern browsers.

Could someone please clarify if this is achievable? If so, I'd greatly appreciate guidance on how to proceed with such an implementation.

Comment: From what I understand all (or at least most) the client-side libraries you mentioned are implemented to use that API so I guess you can do it yourself but you will end up essentially re-implementing them